# Error Based on Stored Procedure Return Value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql-server

I have a ASP.NET C# web page that has a DetailsView in Update Mode. The user types something in and presses a button to update that record on the database.

I would like to add a JavaScript that runs a quick stored procedure and gets a return value. If that return value is less than 1, then I would like my DetailsView update to continue. If the value is greater than 1, then I'd like to stop the update and display an error message: 'ERROR:Greater than 1'.

As always, I appreciate any assistance.

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue in a roundabout way. This isn't my ideal solution, but it works just the same.

I ended up putting this code in my Page_Load. It grabs the users code from the QueryString then runs a SQL query using that user code to get a single value. If that value is greater than 1, the page redirects to an error page.

Again, not ideal, but it serves the purpose.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Runs query to determine if returnValue is greater then 1 then redirects if true 
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(UID) FROM Table WHERE (USER = @USER)";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlParameter UserID = new SqlParameter("@USER", Request.QueryString["usr"]);
        UserID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(UserID);
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        int returnValue;
        returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        sqlConnection1.Close();

        if (returnValue > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("morethanone?usr=" + Request.QueryString["usr"]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a web service or page method to perform the database query and return the result to the client side with the help of `Ajax`.

Here you will find the answer with the implementation the same as you want over here: [Run Stored Procedure with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/599008/1042848)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ajax and Jquery` to achieve this. basically you would invoke a method in code behind where you will run your stored proc and return a success or error message

the Jquery is:

```
$("input[id$='ButtonName']").click(function (e) {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "PageName.aspx/FunctionName",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",

                        success: function (msg) {
                            if (msg.d == 'Success') {
                                //do something
                            }
                            else if (msg.d == 'ERROR') {
                               //do something
                            }
                        }

                    });

                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

and code behind method would be:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string FunctionName()
{
  //run store proc and return success or error 
}
```