# creating and running code from aspx.cs

Tags: c#, ajax

I'm trying to execute the follow code below, from [Run db query (sql server 2005) with ajax. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598900/run-db-query-sql-server-2005-with-ajax-is-it-possible).

```
<Head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function runAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Index.aspx/PerformDatabaseQuery",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Test");
            }
    });
}
</script>
</Head>
```

I then have a button in the body which calls the function

```
<button type="button" onclick="runAjax();"/>
```

The code above resides in Home.cshtml

I'm not entirely sure if I created Index.aspx.cs correct, I clicked on a folder, add new class and simply named the file Index.aspx.cs. I put breakpoints in Index.aspx.cs and it's never hit. The callback function alert("Test") never triggers as well.

If I replace runAjax(); to execute

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function functionTwo() { alert('You clicked the bottom text'); }
</script>
```

The alert will display. May I ask where am I going wrong with this ajax call

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Hi @Izzy I'm fairly new to web development, may I ask how would I check?

Comment: Press the `F12` key. Depending on the browser you'll either have a window popup or docked and in the there you'll have a tab which will say `Console` click on it and refresh your page

Comment: Is it ASP.NET MVC? Or ASP.NET? If the former, there is no concept of web methods, if the latter, there should be no cshtml source files afaik. Also you button may trigger a page reload

Comment: @stuartd, then how could `Home.cshtml` be? Is it some latest update that allows one to use razor in asp.net?

Comment: @Izzy, I only see getPreventDefault() is deprecated, rest or css errors.

stuartd  - no it doesn't inherit that, should it?  Andrei it's MVC, I believe.

Comment: @Master, then you are applying asp.net solution to asp.net mvc app, that won't work straight away. And you should not do that, asp.net mvc should support such scenario naturally. Just have another action method, another controller if you need, and call that with ajax

Comment: @Andrei Okay, thanks for clearing this up for me and helping me understand!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you handle the error function in the ajax call, just to see if there is anything useful being returned by the ajax call (`error: function(xhr, message, exception){ //do something}`. A couple of things I note as well: If you are not passing data then don't include the data option, if this is not on a dev machine on local host in the root then the call will fail as the address 'Index.aspx...' needs to be fully qualified.